# Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template

Tags: php, zend-framework

my config value are

```
   'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'System\Controller\Index' => 'System\Controller\IndexController',
            'System\Controller\Config' => 'System\Controller\ConfigController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array( 
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'system' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        )
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array( 
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
             'system' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/system/index[/:action][/:id]', 
                     'constraints' => array( 
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'System\Controller\Index',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ), 

        ),
    ),
```

and directory stutrue are in pics.

Is there any things else I am missing ? because i am getting error msg in zf2 application .

**Error Msg** :

**Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "system/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'view_manager' => array( 
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'system' => array(__DIR__ . '/../view'),
        )
    ),
```